# Retrieving an intersection of two terms from two different custom taxonomies via API

Tags: custom-taxonomy, rest-api

Running the current version of the API via the WP core and the rest-filter plugin I'm trying to retrieve a set of posts at the intersection of two terms from two different custom taxonomies. Initially I thought `posts?filter[tax1]=term1&filter[tax2]=term2` would do the trick, but sadly that is not the case. Is there a way of doing this via the API (with or without the rest-filter plugin) or do I need to do something to `rest_query_vars` (which I'm also a little unsure about)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is not a way to do this via the core API, though this could change in the future. To retrieve this form of content you have to create a new endpoint.